# table length in ajax table

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var serial_no = 1;
if (response.length > 0) {
  for (var count = 0; count < response.length; count++)

  {
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>' + response[count].id + '</td>';
    html += '<td>€' + response[count].inkoopprijs + '</td>';
    html += '<td>€' + response[count].verkoopprijs + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + response[count].producten + '</td>';
    html += '<td><a href="../prijswijzigen.php?edit=' + response[count].id + '" class="edit_btn">Edit</td>';
    html += '<td><a href="C_R_U_D.php?del=' + response[count].id + '" class="del_btn">Delete</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    serial_no++;
  }
} else {
  html += '<tr><td colspan="3" class="text-center">No Data Found</td></tr>';
}
document.getElementById('post_data').innerHTML = html;
document.getElementById('total_data').innerHTML = response.length;
```

I have this for code for a data table, I made this to support a search function, but I can figure out how to set a table length. I want to set it to ten.

Comment: try this `for (var count = 0; count < response.length; count++) { if(count >= 10) break; ... }`

Comment: @Layhout, somehow I only get 1 result off of my table?

Comment: `if(count > 10)` should do it then.